# How long are metrics retained for SNS in CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I can't seem to find this info anywhere.

Specifically, I'm looking at metrics like `NumberOfMessagesPublished` and `NumberOfNotificationsDelivered`. How far back does CloudWatch retain this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**2 weeks** according to [Monitoring Your Instances Using CloudWatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-cloudwatch.html)

> These statistics are recorded for a period of two weeks, so that you
>   can access historical information and gain a better perspective on how
>   your web application or service is performing.

If you want to [archive metrics beyond 2 weeks](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/)

> If you want to archive metrics beyond 2 weeks you can do so by calling
>   mon-get-stats command from the command line and storing the results in
>   Amazon S3 or Amazon SimpleDB.